# Retain Count of a View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management, retaincount

I am trying to print the retain count of a view controller in the viewDidLoad method. The value returned is 3 .

Can someone please tell why is the value 3 ?

My code is as follows

```
@implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSLog(@"Retain count in View Did Load is %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)(self)));

    }
```

Comment: As the answers indicate, retain count is meaningless.  Even for debugging, you want to use the allocations instrument to find leaks.  That said, every `NSObject` has a `retainCount` property.  There's no need to hit Core Foundation to get that information.

Comment: I think you get a compiler error if you call `retainCount` directly when ARC is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about it. `retainCount` is often temporarily higher than you might expect. Add a `-dealloc` method for debugging/unit tests and make sure it is called when the `viewController` is dismissed and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's 25 for me:

```
2015-11-18 19:53:51.323 test[61900:10880987] Retain count in View Did Load is 25
```

You can't rely on the retain count being any particular number (except that it won't be zero).

If you really want to know how it ended up where it did, use Instruments:

[image: instruments allocation trace]